# How to make a filtered summary in django template involving two models linked with foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am currently learning django and below is the current setup:

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS, default="Pending")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    c_pending = orders.filter(status='Pending').all()

    context = {
        'orders': orders,
        'customers': customers,
        'c_pending': c_pending,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

home.html

```
{% for customer in customers %}
<tr>
    <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{customer.order_set.count}}</td>
    <td>{{c_pending.count}}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

One to third column work flawlessly, except fourth column. The problem is I wish to display in fourth column the no. of orders which is under pending status for each customer but it indeed shows up the total no. of pending orders as a whole.  What steps I am missing in order for django template properly extract the no. of orders for each customer under pending status.  Any help is highly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `c_pending` is just the queryset of *all* pending orders, not per se of that customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c_pending` is just the queryset of *all* pending orders, not per se of that customer. You can annotate the queryset with the number of pending orders:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

def home(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
    customers = Customer.objects.annotate(
        total_orders=Count('order'),
        total_pending=Count('order', filter=Q(order__status='Pending'))
    )

    context = {
        'orders': orders,
        'customers': customers,
        'c_pending': c_pending,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

In the view, you then render this with:

```
{% for customer in customers %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.phone }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.total_orders }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.total_pending }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Willem.  It works flawlessly now in all columns.